# Recursively exclude directory with pattern using tar

Tags: linux, directory, tar

I have a directory with various python packages that I'd like to archive using tar. I need to exclude the numerous `__pycache__` folders that get left behind by the build/testing process but using `--exclude "__pycache__"` will not achieve this. How can I get tar to ignore all subdirectories that match that pattern?

```
tar -cvf myarchive.tar -C ~/myproject package1/ package2/ --exclude "__pycache__"
```

To recreate:

```
me@me-laptop:~/myproject$ pwd
/home/me/myproject
me@me-laptop:~/myproject$ tree
.
├── package1
│   ├── include
│   └── __pycache__
└── package2
    ├── include
    └── __pycache__

6 directories, 0 files
me@me-laptop:~/myproject$ tar -cvf myarchive.tar -C ~/myproject package1/ package2/ --exclude "__pycache__"
package1/
package1/include/
package1/__pycache__/
package2/
package2/include/
package2/__pycache__/
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this with a basic directory tree. Can you show us the directory structure you have on your system?

Comment: added an example

Comment: for reference, I'm  currently on ubuntu 18.04 but this is also happening on centos7

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still can't reproduce this. I'm on an RHEL 7 system with GNU `tar` 1.26 (which would be identical to your CentOS system). Copy-pasting the exact same command from your question works for me.

Comment: my apologies, it does work on centos, i must have used a different flag the time it didn't work. So is it a difference between ubuntu and centos' tar versions?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing as eblock's answer below. `tar`'s manual mentioned that the syntax was `tar options names`. So it would make sense that the `--exclude` option should be placed before the directory names, `package1/ package2/`. I didn't have an Ubuntu distro to verify this assumption, so that was that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `--exclude` switch at the beginning of the command, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders). This solution works on my openSUSE machine, I don't have other distros available right now.

```
host:/tmp # find test*
test1
test1/file1
test1/__pycache__
test1/__pycache__/file1-py
test1/include
test1/include/file1-incl
test2
test2/__pycache__
test2/__pycache__/file2-py
test2/include
test2/include/file2-incl
test2/file2

host: # tar --exclude='__pycache__' -cv test* -f testtar.tar
test1/
test1/file1
test1/include/
test1/include/file1-incl
test2/
test2/include/
test2/include/file2-incl
test2/file2
```

Comment: This works on both Ubuntu and Centos, odd that the centos version accepts the `--exclude` at the end of the line